# How many ways can $k$ DISTINCT numbers have sum $n$?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I'd like to know if there is a formula to calculate the number of ways $k$ **distinct** numbers can have sum $n$.

I know that, without the distinct restriction, this can be done with $\binom{n+k-1}{n}$. As an example if $n=8$ and $k=3$ the formula above return $45$, but the right answer, for what I want is $33$ because these are the right combinations:
$$\{800, 080, 008, 710, 701, 170, 071, 017, 107, 620, 602, 062, 260, 026, 206, 611, 161, 116, 530, 503, 350, 053, 305, 035, 521, 512, 251, 152, 215, 125, 440, 404, 044\}$$ 
As another example, for $n=8$ and $k=4$ the formula return $165$, but I want $86$. I think that the surplus is because the formula considers combinations like $611$, more times: $6ab$, $6ba$, but if $a=b$ this is the same combination.

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Why does $116$ qualify but $332$ does not?

Comment: And by what criterion was $341$ left out?  Your list of $33$ does not tell me what you mean by **distinct**.

Comment: ok ok I was wrong... I forgot some combination...

Comment: Making a complete list, even of a set of smallish size,  is surprisingly difficult to do without repetition or omission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are incorrect in your list of 33. As stated in the comments, there are other possibilities: the variations on 332 (three of these), 341 (six of these) and (although not noted in the comments yet) 422 (three of these). The complete list is:

$ \{ 800, 080, 008, 710, 701, 170, 071, 017, 107, 620, 602, 062, 260, 026, 206, 611, 161, 116, 530, 503, 350, 053, 305, 035, 521, 512, 251, 152, 215, 125, 440, 404, 044, 422, 424, 244, 431, 413, 341, 314, 134, 143, 332, 323, 233 \}$

There are 45.

Now, moving on to your actual question!

Normally in Maths "distinct" means that there are no repeated values.

That would restrict your list to:

$ \{710, 701, 170, 071, 017, 107, 620, 602, 062, 260, 026, 206, 530, 503, 350, 053, 305, 035, 521, 512, 251, 152, 215, 125, 431, 413, 341, 314, 134, 143 \}$

There would then be only 30 possible sets.

However, by "distinct" you may also mean that you do not want to have all the possible variations of (for example) "251." This would reduce your list considerably to:

$ \{017, 026, 035, 125, 134 \}$

You will need to be clearer in stating what it is you want if you want further help...

Comment: Ops XD... You are right...

Comment: But this is what OP did *not* want, $\binom{8+3-1}{3-1}$. Although what OP wants continues to remain a mystery !

Comment: @trueblueanil I know - it is really unclear what the OP means by "distinct."

Comment: as I wrote in the the comment above, I forgot some combination